# JS function Cant get the Value from vbhtml

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, vb.net

How can I get value from my html action link, I tried to set the value in js function and it is work, and the problem is js not get the value form html file, and this forloop only the first one will call the Javascript function.

this is my js function

function selectTemplate() {

```
$('#choose').on('click', function () {

    var objTemplate = $(".styTemplate").val();
    $.post(strRoot + "/Home/Index/", { styTemplate: objTemplate });

});
```

};

and this is my vbhtml code

```
            @For Each item In Model
                Dim currentItem = item

                '<!-- single-awesome-project start -->
                @<div Class="col-md-4 col-sm-4 col-xs-12 @Html.DisplayFor(Function(modelItem) currentItem.strTemplateType)">
                    <div Class="single-awesome-project">
                        <div Class="awesome-img">
                            <a href="#"><img src="@Url.Content("~/Content/TemplateCSS/img/portfolio/" & currentItem.strTemplateType & ".jpg")" alt="" /></a>
                            <div Class="add-actions text-center">
                                <div Class="project-dec">
                                    <a Class="venobox" data-gall="myGallery" href="@Url.Content("~/Content/TemplateCSS/img/portfolio/" & currentItem.strTemplateType & ".jpg")">
                                        <h4>@currentItem.strTemplateName</h4>
                                        <span> Web Development</span>
                                        @Html.ActionLink("Choose", "companyInfomation", "Home", New With {.id = "choose"}, New With {.styTemplate = currentItem.strTemplateName})

                                    </a>

                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                '<!-- single-awesome-project end -->

            Next

        </div>


        <script>

            selectTemplate();

        </script>
```

Comment: You do not have an element with `class="styTemplate"`

Comment: Also, If you are rendering item's inside a loop, use a generic selector for your click event binding and relative methods like `closest` and `find`.

Comment: Are you want to handle all elements with `choose` as its class? Also you may need to fix the link with proper route value & HTML attribute definitions: `@Html.ActionLink("Choose", "companyInfomation", "Home", New With { ... }, New With { .class = "choose" })` and handle `$('.choose').click()` event instead.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe it's better to use onclick attribute? Use this instead of Html.ActionLink:

```
<a href="@Url.Action("companyInfomation", "Home")" onclick="YourJSFunction(@currentItem.strTemplateName)">Choose</a>
```